# Latin Squares and Olderogge Code

Tags: cryptography, coding-theory, latin-square

So I have two Latin Squares, $A$ and $B$ that form a pair of MOLS of order $m$.
I then have an Olderogge code formed from $A$ and $B$, where each binary vector of length $m^2$ is encoded as a codeword of length $m^2 + 4m + 1$.

For the code $C$, I want to prove that it's linear, determine its dimension, and most importantly, determine the minimum distance.

How would I do this?

Thanks.